# Getting BQ error: Out of stack space due to deeply nested query expression during query resolution in google bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am working on a project where I need to compute scores for each record in a table based on the weights of different features. I have generated the weights using logistic regression. I have also generated a query that does the score weighted computation for all features using weights generated by LR. There are around 500 features in total.

However, when I run the query, I get an error saying `Out of stack space due to deeply nested query expression`. I understand that this is because the query is complex as it compute weighted score for lot of feats in select statement. But I don't know how to simplify the query or avoid this error.

Is there any way to rewrite the query or use a different approach to achieve the same result without getting this error? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Example query:
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION LR(x float64) RETURNS FLOAT64 AS ( 1/(1+ EXP(case when x > 100 then 100 else x end)) );
SELECT Id, LR( -( 0.01 * feat_1 + 0.04 * feat_2 ......{for all features})  )

Comment: Do you need a function here? Why not just create a column which is just weighted average(`wa_feature`) and apply the sigmoid function on  `wa_feature` ? The solution would be vectorized then and faster.

Comment: Because the sigmoid function is used only once have tried to directly use its definition instead of defining it separately, but it yielded the same result. If you mean something different can you please specify the query structure? Thanks